# How to return value for key from a jsonb column?

Tags: postgresql, json

I've successfully created the below table on 9.5.1.0:

```
  CREATE TABLE json_test (
    id serial primary key,
    data jsonb
  );
```

and successfully inserted this record:

```
  INSERT INTO json_test (data) VALUES ('{"0":"INVALID","1":"BELOW","2":"EQUAL","3":"ABOVE"}')
```

and I am successfull in returning the entire record that I inserted via:

```
  SELECT * FROM json_test WHERE data::jsonb ? '1';
```

but how do I return the value associated with '1', i.e. "BELOW" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [post](http://clarkdave.net/2013/06/what-can-you-do-with-postgresql-and-json/) gives you your answer:

```
CREATE TABLE json_test 
(
  id serial primary key,
  data jsonb
);
INSERT INTO json_test (data) VALUES ('{"0":"INVALID","1":"BELOW","2":"EQUAL","3":"ABOVE"}');
```

You specify the element that you wish to extract thus:

```
SELECT id, data->>'1' AS whatever FROM json_test;
```

And the result is:

```
id      whatever
1       BELOW
```

There are a [shedload](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) of new json functions in PostgreSQL - there could be more examples (hint PostgreSQL team...).